# Very simple rest webservice on ruby on rails

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, rest

I am trying to implement very-very simple webservice to practice with my iphone application, for example storing geolocation data and retrieving it from web. I started with Ruby on Rails, read some books and install it on my pc.

I install Ruby installer for Windows, then

```
gem update --system
gem source -a http://gemcutter.org
gem install rails 
*then I install sqlite3*
gem install sqlite3-ruby
*and I even install webservice gem*
```

All working fine and I wrote some simple applications and can access it all on http://localhost:3000. Then I saw this video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6r_l3cAS9s in which you can see simple restful webservice. As I understand there are no any additional configuration to apps to be a simple webservice. I did exactly what show in this movie and install Fiddler and another rest test client to test this service. I cant get any xml from my app. Fiddler get me my html from http://localhost:3000/words and this rest client http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/ get my again my html page with content type text/html. How can I get XML to start working with this app as webservice?

I use Rails 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, ruby on rails has RESTful service by default. My error was trying to access url http://localhost:3000/words in rest client. If I connect to http://localhost:3000/words.xml instead I immediately get access to my app via XML.

Comment: This helps me understand how to test a basic web service.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be difficult to get xml response. You might want to peak into [TodoAPI](https://github.com/vipinnagpal/TodoAPI) and the client for this app as [TodoAPIClient](https://github.com/vipinnagpal/TodoAPIClient). The client uses HTTParty. You may get the response using Curl for terminal.